# How to get offset value of a large amount of span's with a common class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I currently have a large amount of span's all with a common class (as you probably guessed from the title). When I try:

```
$(".span-class").offset().top;
```

I am trying to check for a collision between one element and all of the spans without creating over 10 unique id's and `.offset` calls. But I only recieve the `.offset().top` value for the first element with the class in the HTML.

So is there a way to check the position on all these elements without 10 or so extra lines of code? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `.each` loop..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var spanArr = [];
$("span.span-class").each(function () {
   spanArr.push($(this).offset().top);        
});
```

Comment: Thank you! This method actually puts out each individual value. Now how can I push those values to an array?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an other way to solve this using [map](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) instead of [each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/). Your question is clearly a usecase for map.

```
var offSetops = $(".span-class").map(function(){
  return $(this).offset().top;
}).get();
```

```js
var offSetops = $(".span-class").map(function(){
  return $(this).offset().top;
}).get();
console.log(offSetops);
```

```css
.span-class{
  display:block;
  height: 10px;
  margin: 2px;
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="span-class"></span>
<span class="span-class"></span>
<span class="span-class"></span>
<span class="span-class"></span>
<span class="span-class"></span>
```

Comment: Thanks Roque! However, why is it best to use .map over .each. Your code returned the exact same array as DsRaj. What is more important when it comes to .map?

Comment: I would not say it is best. I wish I could say it is more efficient but with current implementation it is probably not even true. So the answer is just that it is slightly shorter, more readable and I find it more appropriate. `map` "transforms" an iterable into another. It is done for this purpose, and only this purpose. It is easy to see what is the purpose of the code (even with more complicated examples). `each` (or `forEach` in plain-js) is a functional for loop. You can replicate the `map` behaviour with it and a beforehand initialised array, but why should you? You have `map` for this.

Comment: `map` also allows you chainings. E.g. `arr.map(transform).map(otherTransform).etc...`

Answer (score 0):

Try it..

```
var offSetops = [];

$(".span-class").each(function(){
    var offsetTop = $(this).offset().top;
    offsetops.push(offsetTop);
})
console.log(offSetops);
```

Comment: I believe this worked, however. Is there a way to get the values and push them to an array?

Comment: @Prs, you are incorrectly using `map` as if it was `each` here. It is a good idea to use `map` instead of `each` in the current case. However, do not push in the body of the map function. Return the element you want to be pushed. The resulting array will be the result of the map call. Please refer to the [`map` method](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) and check the difference with the [`each` method](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/).

Comment: This pushes all the values to an array, however all the values are the same. Why is that? All of the span's have a different .offset().top position